# How to "execute" HTML+Javascript page with Node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js

So, I have my Node.js script. And I have some HTML page which contains HTML with JavaScript (jquery) in it. How can I load it and get result of execution of JavaScript on this page?

Comment: If screen scraping is what your after, check out: http://blog.nodejitsu.com/jsdom-jquery-in-5-lines-on-nodejs

Comment: My HTML page does some manipulations with divs -- and I need to get the result of those manipulations. It's not the screenscrapping to get the source HTML w/ Javascript, but actually the result of their execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like JSDOM should do it.

https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom

Comment: Right, but can't figure out how to I get not just HTML/JS of the window, but the result of their execution there.

Answer (score 5):

You can check the zombie.js project :
http://zombie.labnotes.org/

It should load the page mostly as in a real browser.

Comment: Great project!! It directly solves my problem of loading HTML after running the javascript!

Answer (score 1):

Also, a great solution is https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer. Which is Headless Chrome Node API and maintained by Chrome DevTools team.

Comment: But it is very slow at loading pages, while still faster than competitors like Phantom