# How to parse a webpage that includes Javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, html-parsing, jsoup

I've got a webpage that creates a table using Javascript. Right now I'm using JSoup in my Java project to parse the webpage. By the way JSoup isn't able to run Javascript so the table isn't generated and the source of the webpage is incomplete. 
How can I include the HTML code created by that script in order to parse its content using JSoup? Can you provide a simple example? Thank you!

Webpage example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A blank HTML5 page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        table.appendChild(tr);
        document.body.appendChild(table);
    </script>
    <p>First paragraph</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The output should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            A blank HTML5 page
        </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var table = document.createElement("table");
            var tr = document.createElement("tr");
            table.appendChild(tr);
            document.body.appendChild(table);   
        </script>
        <table>
            <tr></tr>
        </table>
        <p>
            First paragraph
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

By the way, JSoup doesn't include the table tag as it isn't able to execute Javascript. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You're probably better off trying to interface with the AJAX service the Javascript is using to populate the table.

Comment: @chrylis There's now AJAX service I think!

Comment: @ClaudioSantos It is not a duplicate as in that question they are asking how to get values from a script. I want to parse the HTML output of that script, it's different!

Comment: @Angelo I believe that answer could help you.

Comment: It is not a duplicate as in the other question he's asking something different. In the answer there's not what I'm looking for as he wants to extract informations from the static script. I want to parse the html generated by that script (IT'S DIFFERENT!). Rhino could be helpful but it seems that the documentation doesn't explain something about Javascript evaluation and parsing

Answer (score 4):

**First possibility**

You have some options outside Jsoup, i.e. employing a "real" browser and interact with it. An excellent choice for this would be [selenium webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp). With selenium you can use different browsers as back end, and maybe in your case the very lightweight [htmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) would do already. If more complicated JavaScript is called there is often no other choice then running a full browser. Luckily, [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) is out there and its footprint is not too bad (headless and all).

**Second possibility**

Another approach could be that you grab the javascript source with JSoup and start a JavaScript interpreter within Java. For that you could use [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino). However, if you go that path you might as well use HtmlUnit directly, which is probably a bit less bulky.