# Parser don't download inside of <div>

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup, jaunt-api

I have a problem with using a parser in Java.
I would like to do get informations from a website.
The problem is that the parser is not downloading what is inside some .
In the source code (when I open through a web browser) I can see what is inside , but in a parser I can’t.

Example:
In a web browser:

```
<div>something lalala</div>
```

In a parser:

`<div></div>`

What is wrong? How can I use parser to get the source of `<div>`?
I tried JSoup and Jaunt, but the problem is the same.

How to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I suspect that your div is filled with content by JavaScript after (or while) page is loaded which jsoup doesn't support (it is parser, not browser). If that is the case then you will need web driver like selenium.

Comment: here is an answer i gave to a similar question once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465510/how-to-parse-a-webpage-that-includes-javascript/19467873#19467873