# Get data from web page using Jsoup return empty results

Tags: javascript, android, jsoup

I am working in get wheather conditions from a web. http://trestlebikepark.com/

When I  use the Inspect Element Function from Chrome or Firefox I find  the div class with the text I need (34F).

```
<div class="overlayWeather">
                <div class="title">Current</div>
                <div class="icon"><span class="climacon sun"></span></div>
                <div class="temperature">34 °F</div>
                <div class="conditions">Sunny</div>
            </div>
```

But in the Source Code the content is empty.

```
        <div class="currentStatusOverlay">
            <div class="overlayWeather">
                <div class="title">Current</div>
                <div class="icon"><span class="climacon"></span></div>
                <div class="temperature"></div>
                <div class="conditions"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How I can get this texts?

I tried

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            Elements div = doc.select("div.temperature");
            String temp = div.text();
```

I receive empty results

I understand than the table is populated after the page is loaded, but I cant find information on how get this values in an android textView

Comment: Jsoup doesn't execute JavaScript, so it won't see any dynamically-generated content.  You could try an actual browser or a browser front-end like Selenium.

Comment: You might want to look into this answer I gave once to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465510/how-to-parse-a-webpage-that-includes-javascript/19467873#19467873 or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904776/parse-javascript-with-jsoup?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this instead of Jsoup: Send a Http request to

```
https://secure.winterparkresort.com/JSON/RtpJsonServices.asmx/getTrestleConditions?callback=null
```

This will give you some JSON like:

```
null({"iconClass":"sun","Temperature":34,"Conditions":"Sunny","openLifts":0,"openTrails":0});
```

And you have the information you want.