# I can't parse for image src using JSOUP.

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I am trying to parse all Image src using jsoup in Link: http://kissmanga.com/Manga/One-Piece/One-Piece-790--Heaven-and-Earth?id=232851

My code to parse:

```
 Document document= Jsoup.connect(params[0]).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 "
            + "(Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
            + "Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36")
            .timeout(10000).followRedirects(false).get();

        Log.d("DisPlay",document.toString());
        Elements  elements =document.select("div#divImage p");
        Log.d("DisPlay",elements.toString());
        for(Element e:elements)
          {

        Log.d("ImageChapter",e.attr("src"));

         }
```

But i get Nothing. Someone can help me get all image in this chapter manga.

Comment: The site you are trying to get data seems to use javascript. What do you see from  Log.d("DisPlay",document.toString());?

Comment: Jsoup does not interpret Javascript. Here is an answer to a related question I once gave that might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465510/how-to-parse-a-webpage-that-includes-javascript/19467873#19467873

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, element you get is not `img` tag, so you cannot get attribute `src`. You shoul use `document.select("div#divImage p img");` for getting the `img` tag, from that you can get attribute `src`.

Secondly, this page load image by `javascript` you can check page source, you can find that they use

```
$("#divImage img").load(function() {});
```

Please check where the list of image is installed. From that you can parse image link by getting the `javascript`. But i am sure that this is very difficult.