# How to access client-side javascript variable from external page?

Tags: node.js

Let's say, when we open link `https://example.com` and that page generates javascript variable, called `xyz`, so we can access it from browser's `Inspect` console:

```
console.log(xyz);
```

However, how can we get & read that variable from `node.js` ?  (the external link needs to be rendered like in browser, to get javascript values out of it).

Comment: There is [10 years old topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222469/how-to-execute-htmljavascript-page-with-node-js), but I doubt it is applicable now and there should have changed many things in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different approaches to get the variable, depending how they are created.

- variable is directly in source code so you can simply parse it using regEx for example.
- variable is being evaluated in JS runtime, in this case you need to mock the browser environment using [PhantomJS](https://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html), which is quite heavy.

Comment: yes, i have been talking about runtime evaluation. so, PhantomJS or Nightwatch seems possible route..

Answer (score 0):

One possible way seems to use plugin like [Nightwatch](https://nightwatchjs.org/). However, in the past it depended selenium, which is a bit heavy.